# How can I get rid of "no such property" when testing a class that accesses Item.constraints.xyz?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking, spock

The following constellation in a unit test returns: `No such property: title for class: myproject.Item Possible solutions: title`

**ItemController.groovy**

```
def add = { 
    [itemInstance: new Item(), titleMin: Item.constraints.title.size.min() ] 
}
```

**ItemControllerSpec.groovy**

```
mockDomain Item
def result = controller.add()
```

**How can I mock out that constraints line?**

*Note: I just want the test to run instead of failing due to that line.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via [metaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses). In `setUp()`, write something like: 
`Item.metaClass.'static'.constraints = [ title: [ size: [ min: {5}, max: {30} ] ] ]`

Comment: That failed in my case. However, thanks to your hint, Victor, I was able to come up with the following solution: `Item.metaClass.'static'.getConstraints = { [ title: [size:5..20] ] }`

Answer (score 1):

If your test class extends `GrailUnitTestCase`, call `mockForConstraintsTests(Item)` before the test executes. If you can't extend this class, try invoking `grails.test.MockUtils.prepareForConstraintsTests(Item)` before the test executes.

Comment: Don, both variants fail with the same error message as described in my initial post. I've also tried it with a newly generated ItemControllerTests.groovy with nothing else but the `testSomething` in place. Have you had a similar situation yourself, where it worked?